# One Action returns Future[Result] while other returns Accumultor[]

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

I have created the following two `Actions`

```
def action1: Action[Either[MaxSizeExceeded, AnyContent]] = silhouette.SecuredAction.async(parse.maxLength(maxAllowedBodySize, parse.anyContent)(materializer)) { ...}


def action2:Action[AnyContent] = silhouette.UserAwareAction.async { ...}
```

While unit testing them, I found that result of `action1`'s return is `Future[Result]` while that of `action2` is `Accumulator[ByteString, Result]`

```
val response:Accumulator[ByteString,Result] = testEnv.controller.action1(request)

val response:Future[Result] = userTestEnv.controller.action2(request)
```

I can't quite figure out why there is a difference? Why are return type different?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is that for `Action` of type [Either[MaxSizeExceeded, AnyContent]], the `Action` returns `Accumulator` - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaEssentialAction

In general, it seems that if `Play` knows that the body can be fit in memory then it returns `Future[Result]` otherwise it returns `Accumulator`.